# Track empties to rigged+animated characted

Tags: animation, rigging, constraints, tracking, empty

So I have this rigged character that does a little dance. I need all the empties to keep their current positions on the mesh for something later. Essentially when the character moves, the empties should move with it keeping their place as they are now. Any ideas?

[image: character with empties on its surface]